# Default initialization vs. copy initialization from default-constructed value

Tags: c++, c++11

Let `thing` be a default-constructible and move-constructible type. Consider the following two initializations:

```
thing t1;          // (1)
auto t2 = thing{}; // (2)
```

- (1) default-constructs `t1`.
- (2) default-constructs a temporary of type `thing` and moves it into `t2`.

**Under which circumstances will the move in (2) be elided?**

In modern style C++ initializations, the type usually either doesn't appear at all or appears on the right. For example:

```
auto copy = vec;                              // Type doesn't appear

auto p_derived = std::make_unique<derived>(); // Type appears naturally on the right

// Putting the type on the right here makes it explicit that the upcast is intended
auto p_base = std::unique_ptr<base>{ std::make_unique<derived>() };
```

Using (2) would be consistent with those styles, whereas using (1) wouldn't.

Also, when using (1) with a long typename, the variable name appears far on the right. When using (2), the variable name is equally appparent no matter how long the typename is.

**Does that mean that (2) is preferable over (1) for the sake of consistency?**

Comment: Not related to copy elsiion anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Under which circumstances will the move in (2) be elided?

When the compiler chooses to elide. This is practically always on modern compilers. However, there is no guaranteed copy elision in C++11 (nor C++14).

> Using (2) would be consistent with those styles, whereas using (1) wouldn't.
>
> Does that mean that (2) is preferable over (1) for the sake of consistency?

There is very little advantage in consistency for consistency's sake.

It is useful to understand why the type is on the right in your examples, and why (this meaning of) `auto` exists. The type is on the right because it is needed there for template instantiation. Still a type has to be on the left side also to have the syntax of a declaration. The type is also the return type of the right hand expression, so `auto` was introduced to allow deduction from that expression. This is advantageous because we avoid fragile duplication of the type.

(1) has no duplication, so there is no de-duplication advantage when introducing `auto`. There is no right hand expression and there is no need to introduce one. (2) has unnecessary extra boilerplate, and the added requirement for the type to be movable.

> Also, when using (1) with a long typename, the variable name appears far on the right. When using (2), the variable name is equally appparent no matter how long the typename is.

This is a weak argument in my opinion. You should avoid unnecessarily long typenames anyway, but in case you're stuck with one, you can simply place them in separate lines:

```
thing_with_extra_long_type_name_for_some_reason<omg_it_doesnt_end>
  t1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Which is preferable is a matter of opinion.  I will not weigh in, that is not what SO is for.

Every modern compiler that supports C++11 will elide that move, unless you pass explicit compiler flags to never elide things.

In C++17 there is no move to elide; the `thing{}` is a prvalue, and prvalues are not objects in C++17 but rather instructions to create objects (which may instantiate an anonymous temporary object, but not in this case).

The `auto x =` *prvalue* `;` statement causes the prvalue instructions to be used to construct `x`.